# javascript class variable scope confusion (socket.io events)

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm using node with express and socket.io to create a game server. I've put the game server in a extra module.
I have the problem that I can't access the game server object within the io event.
How do I solve this problem or should I structure my project differently?

```
// gameServer.js
'use strict'
var io = require('socket.io');
var socketioJwt = require('socketio-jwt');
var config = require('../config.js');

class GameServer {
    constructor(http) {
        this.io = new io(http);
        this.connectedUsers = [];

        this.initSocket();
    }

    initSocket() {
        console.log('users', this.connectedUsers);
        this.io.on('connection', this.onConnection);
    }

    onConnection(socket) {
        console.log('users', this.connectedUsers); // undefined
    }
}
```

I initialize the server like that:

```
'use strict'
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);

// init game server
var gameServerApp = new GameServer(http);

http.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

I assume this is a common question but I can't figure out how to solve it.

Comment: can you print the error?

Comment: this.connectedUsers in onConnection() is undefined but I expect it to be connectedUsers of the GameServer instance.

Comment: check what `this` returns

Comment: I've actually never used JavaScript classes, but try assigning 'this' to a variable in initSocket and then using that variable instead. e.g., var self = this; this.io.on( 'connection', self.onConnection );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `bind` `this` to `this.onConnection`

```
initSocket() {
        console.log('users', this.connectedUsers);
        this.io.on('connection', this.onConnection.bind(this));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Is there a  way to automate this in some way? If not I have to bind it on every callback in my class (which are quite a few).

Comment: As per my knowledge, I would have used `bind`